# Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build - Android Platform

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to build the app for Android with google play console, but after I enter the build command  eas build --platform android it gives me this error :

```
Compressing project files and uploading them to EAS Build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build

Reason: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\PC2-User\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\6fa14d4c-e756-4389-b7d0-1946601b58b3-shallow-clone'
    Error: build command failed.
- Compressing project files
```

How can I fix this , so I can make the build for android

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution got the same issue with both IOS and Android